# Angular XLSX library, export an array of objects

Tags: angular, typescript, xlsx

This is my mock data

```
mockData: any[] = [
  {
    "id": "456",
    "requestType": "Test",
    "requestDate": "10/15/20",
    "status": "Fail",
    "product": [
       {
         "productName": "product 1",
         "productQty": "12"
       },
       {
         "productName": "product 2",
         "productQty": "22"
       }
    ]
  }
]
```

**.ts:**

```
toExportFileName(excelFileName: string): string {
    var date = new Date();
    return `${excelFileName}_${date.getMonth() + 1}${date.getDate()}${date.getFullYear()}.xlsx`;
  }

  exportAsExcelFile(json: any[], excelFileName: string): void {
    const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json);
    const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = { Sheets: { 'data': worksheet }, SheetNames: ['data'] };
    XLSX.writeFile(workbook, this.toExportFileName(excelFileName));
  }

  exportToExcel() {
    this.exportAsExcelFile(this.mockData, 'Shado_Test_Report');
  }
```

**Actual Results:**

[image: Actual Output]

**Expected Results:**

[image: Expected Output]

I'm trying to tweak the logic to handle the array of objects and specify the position in the xl, Can I achieve the above expected results based on the mockData with xlsx library ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by changing

```
const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json);
```

**to:**

```
@ViewChild('reportTable') reportTable: ElementRef;

const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet=XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(this.reportTable.nativeElement);
```

Now I'm exporting HTML Table to Excel and I see the expected results now

Comment: I just want to thanks you a lot, your code works really well for me.